# I need to remove my bluetooth device everytime I want to connect

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, release-odin, odin

Guys.

I have Haylou GT1 Plus and it works fine on OS 6.1. However, everytime I turn my bluetooth off or disconnect my earbuds and try to connect them again later, I need to remove them in the Bluetooth settings to be able to pair. When I do not remove the device in the system settings, they connect but are mute. This bug also happens when I try to use Blueman.

Any know/suggested solution?

Thank you!

Best,

Answer (score 0):

Frankly speaking, elementary os is not really an ideal distro which you would use to get a seamless wireless connectivity experience. It seems to handle low-bandwidth wifi just fine but when it comes to bluetooth it always has a couple of bugs popping up.

To answer your question, no need to worry just hang on, the elementary team will fix it in future patches.